# Get a list of users in nested active directory groups

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryentry

I have a structure of groups (one main group with sub-groups) in active directory.

How can I get the list of all members (users) of all the groups using the main group DN?

I found many examples for finding nested groups for a specific user, but could find how it works the other way around.  (I'm using C#)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A search using the "LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN" should work.
Something like: (requires at least Windows 2003 SP2):

(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=Admin,OU=Security,DC=DOM,DC=NT)

-jim